# Show that $\mathbb Z_2$ is the only field with two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I'm struggling with this assigment and I need some tips/hints to solve this.

> In a field there is the additional requirement that $0\ne1$, hence a field has at least two elements. Show that $\mathbb Z_2$ is the only field with two elements.

Comment: *Hint* A field with 2 elements and with $0\ne 1$ is necessarily $\{0,1\}$. How do these elements behave with respect to the operations?

Comment: "Only" field in what sense? More importantly, do you understand why it is important to ask the question I just asked?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit your question to tell us what your thoughts are about what your question means and how to show it. @GitGud 's comment is important.

Comment: @GitGud The only $\mathbb Z$ field with 2 elements

Comment: I think you have missed @GitGud 's point. There's no such thing as a "$\mathbb{Z}$ field", there are just fields. You may be thinking about the fields $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Clearly only one of those has two elements. But that's NOT what the question is about. Hint: think "isomorphism".

Comment: As @GitGud said, you need to understand "only" better than you appear to. **Any**  two-element set, like $\{4,7\}$ can be made into a field by suitably defining its addition and multiplication tables. So there are a huge number of $2$-element fields. But all of them are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$, and "only" must be understood in this sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field with only two elements {$0',1'$}.

Note that for addition table we have $$ 0'+0'=0', 0'+1'=1', 1'+1'=0',1'+0'=1'$$

For multiplication  we have $$ 0'*0'=0',0'*1'=0',1'*0'=0', 1'*1'=1'$$

That defines an isomorphism $$ \phi : F\to \mathbb Z_2 $$ between our field $F$ and $  \mathbb Z_2$ defined by $$\phi (0')=0\text { and } \phi (1')=1$$

Comment: Upvoting because this is correct, but I wish you'd waited a while in hopes the OP would realize that the question was about isomorphisms.

Comment: I find this answer incomplete. It's lacking the more troublesome (though easy) part which is to prove that the "addition and multiplication tables are unique".

Comment: @GitGud The assumption is that$ F$ is a field, so for example $1'* 
 1'$ has no other option except to be$ 1$' and same for other operations.

Comment: Yes, but this needs to be verified.

Comment: Sure, for a starter it is a good practice to verify every little detail.